# Haskell applicative functor - compilation failure

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm trying to chain together functions via the applicative functor pattern, but I'm having a problem compiling my code:

```
import Control.Applicative

buildMyList :: Float -> Float -> [Float]
buildMyList ul tick = [p | p <- [0,tick..ul]]

myFunctionChain :: [Float]
myFunctionChain = reverse <$> buildMyList 100 1
```

When I attempt to compile this I get the following compilation error:

```
Couldn't match type 'Float' with '[a0]'
Expected type: [[a0]]
  Actual type: [Float]
In the return type of call of 'buildMyList'
```

It seems to me that I haven't managed to match the expected return context with the actual context. Not having enough experience in this area, I cant get any further!

Comment: You don't need `Applicative` here. Ordinary function application will do: `reverse (buildMyList 100 1)` or `reverse $ buildMyList 100 1`.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. It's meant to be a toy example, as I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work, so that I can build out my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

The `Applicative` could be better explained using `bulldMyList`.
Assume you want to build an array of square matrix:
`[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1, 0) ...]`. Using list comprehensions:

```
buildMyMatrix :: Int -> Int -> [(Int, Int)]
buildMyMatrix maxX maxY = [(x, y) | x <- [0..maxX], y <- [0..maxY]]
```

Using applicative combinators it can be rewritten as:

```
buildMyMatrix maxX maxY = pure (\x y -> (x, y)) <*> [0..maxX] <*> [0..maxY]
```

And according to applicative laws we can rewrite `pure f <*> x = f <$> x`, for all `f` and `x`:

```
buildMyMatrix maxX maxY = (\x y -> (x, y)) <$> [0..maxX] <*> [0..maxY]
```

---

I had to use slightly more complicated `buildMyMatrix`, as your `buildMyList` is too trivial to benefit from Applicative:

```
buildMyList :: Float -> Float -> [Float]
buildMyList ul tick = [p | p <- [0,tick..ul]]
buildMyList ul tick = id <$> [0,tick..ul] -- [by functor identity law]:
buildMyList ul tick = [0,tick..ul]
```

Comment: thanks for this. I guess I was just trying to understand how I can chain together functions that are functors, in an elegant way. I suppose I could use do notation

Comment: If you want to chain functions of the form `Applicative f => a -> f b` or `Monad m => a -> m b`, there are many different ways, depending how you'd like to chain them. [Recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150825/how-can-i-use-with-a-maybe-a) has already two answers, which are probably interesting to work thru (e.g. which instances apply). I find both obscure, but they show the power of the abstraction.